# angular full calendar non allday event re-size doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, fullcalendar

I am trying to re-size events functionality of full calendar. I am able to re-size all day events but i am unable to re-size events having end time and allDay false.

following are my events :

```
 $scope.events = [
      {id: 999,title: 'Full Day Event',start: new Date(y, m, d - 3, 16, 0),allDay: true},
      {title: 'Birthday Party',start: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 19, 0),end: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 22, 30),allDay: false},
    ];
```

and this is my calendar config:

```
$scope.uiConfig = {
      calendar:{
        height: 450,
        editable: true,
        header:{
          left: 'title',
          center: '',
          right: 'today prev,next'
        },
        eventClick: $scope.alertOnEventClick,
        eventDrop: $scope.alertOnDrop,
        eventResize: $scope.alertOnResize,
        eventRender: $scope.eventRender
      }
    }
```

;

you can find the plunk here : [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZSsBkYz8p40B46lB5Iha?p=preview)

please help
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UI Calendar is using FullCalendar behind the hood. The latter does not seems to have such functionnality. If an event is set as `allDay: false` it can only be resized in `week` mode. Here is a link to the related issue on Github https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar/issues/207